# Software development using SNMP

Tags: java, networking, snmp

I would like to write a code in java for network management and monitoring using snmp. Can somebody tell me how to go about with this? what are the inputs that are needed?

Thanks,
ann

Comment: Could you explain a little more about what exactly you want? Your question doesn't have enough details to answer. Where are you currently stuck? What have you done so far?

Comment: I am in an idea of developing a network management and monitoring software.I Thought of using SNMP to develop the software.I m not sure about all the details I would need to give as an input for the software.I am not sure about how to go about with the coding.

Answer (score 2):

I also recommend SNMP4J unless you're willing to pay for [AdventNet SNMP library](http://www.webnms.com/snmp/). Looks like adventnet got bought.

- Usually you create an SNMP target(snmp version, host, authentication)
- Set the list of OIDs to query
- Retrieve the results or update some values

For your other question, SNMP is the protocol and SNMP4J is a java library to help you talk to that protocol.

Comment: SNMP library is free, but if you need support you need to pay for it. I've been usin Adventnet g it for quite sometime now and its pretty simple compared to SNMP4J.

Answer (score 0):

The [SNMP4J](http://www.snmp4j.org/) project might be a good place to start.

Comment: but can u tel me what exactly is SNMP4J?what is the difference between SNMP and SNMP4J